# How do I convert a tibble with sentences into bullet points in Microsoft word using rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, stringr

I have an excel file with a column that has comments which I'm reading into R as a tibble. I would like to then knit each comment into a bullet point (or just a new line sentence) using rmarkdown. Code below reproduces a small sample to replicate what I have -

```
library(tidyverse)
comments <- 
  c("I haven't experienced a proactive approach to our work but rather reacting and responding to community needs",
    "The board does not have regular exposure to many staff")

comments <- comments %>% as_tibble()
```

Here is what I'm trying to achieve when knitting to word -

[image]

I tried using the following code -

```
for(row in comments){
   cat("\n", row, "\n")
}
```

However it does not add spacing and just prints all rows of the tibble like a single paragraph. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the list structure using either `-` or `*`. Both should work. Remember `results='asis'` in chunk options. Example

````
```{r, results='asis'}
for(row in comments){
  cat(paste0("* ", row, "\n"))
}
```
````

Or even simpler (but might be cheating since it only allows for one column at a time)

````
```{r, results='asis'}
cat(paste0("- ",comments[[1]], "\n"))
```
````